# How to calculate the following rectangle contour integral in complex analysis?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

There are four points in the complex plane: $A(-a,-jw)$, $B(a,-jw)$, $C(a,0)$, $D(-a,0)$, the contour goes anticlockwise on this rectangle, and here we have the integrand function being a normal gaussian distribution which is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{(-\frac{z^2}{2})}$.

My question is how can I get its integral on the two vertical line $\vec{BC}$ and $\vec{DA}$ ? Namely, $\int_{\vec{DA}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{(-\frac{z^2}{2})}dz$.
Thank you for your answers in advance.